# trying to get categories name along with the images in dynamic table rows

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

Habing this code for coldfusion but after trying couple of times, i am always ending up showing categories multiple times and images multiple times too, i tried using the group attribute but that it also not doing its work, not sure what is going wrong

here is my complete code

```
<cfparam name="url.mode" default="">
<cfquery name="ImagesCategories">
    select * from rivereast_gallerycategories 
</cfquery>
<div id="spacingorder" align="right"><cfoutput>#DateFormat(now(),'long')#</cfoutput></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <h2>View Gallery Contents</h2>
    <div align="right"> </div>
    <div align="center">
      <cfset variables.newrow = False>
      <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="5" class="borderspacing">
        <tr>
        <cfif ImagesCategories.recordcount>
           <cfoutput query="ImagesCategories">
           #gallerycategory#
            <cfquery name="filesListings">
                select c.galleryCatID,c.ImageID,c.ImageName as name,c.updatedon
                from rivereast_gallery c
                order by updatedon desc 
            </cfquery>
            <cfloop query="filesListings">
            <cfif variables.newrow EQ true>
                <tr>
            </cfif>
            <td height="30" valign="middle">
            <div id="previewArea">
            <cfset filename = Listlast(filesListings.name,'~')>
            
            
                <img src="#request.weburl#uploads/#filename#" class="img-fluid"><br>
            
            <input type="checkbox" class="ImagesDelete" name="delItems" data-id="#filesListings.imageID#">&nbsp;Delete #filesListings.currentRow#
            </div>
            </td>
            <cfif filesListings.currentRow MOD 5 EQ 0>
                </tr>
                <cfset variables.newrow = true>
            <cfelse>
              <cfset variables.newrow = false>
            </cfif>
            </cfloop>
       </cfoutput> 
       <cfelse>
       <td colspan="3" align="center"><h2>No Files Found</h2></td>
       </cfif>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <cfif filesListings.recordcount>
        <div><input type="button" name="deleImages" id="delImages" class="button btn btn-info" value="Delete"></div>
      </cfif>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what went wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing the data, but it might be this.  You are running this query inside a query loop.

```
       <cfquery name="filesListings">
            select c.galleryCatID,c.ImageID,c.ImageName as name,c.updatedon
            from rivereast_gallery c
            order by updatedon desc 
        </cfquery>
```

Note that it has no `where clause`.  That could be the reason for seeing the same data more than once.

Assuming your database is somewhat normalized, the recommended fix is to just have one query that gets data from both tables at once.  The sql would look something like this.

```
select JustTheFieldsYouNeed
from rivereast_gallerycategories c join rivereast_gallery g 
   on c.categoryID = g.categoryID
where some condition is met
```

Comment: the problem with one query is if i use it frm grouping, the groups all stay at the top and images appear underneath it

Comment: A common mistake with grouped query output is forgetting that it requires *sorted* query results.

Answer (score 0):

I'd join the two queries

```
SELECT c.*, g.galleryCatID, g.ImageID, g.ImageName as name, g.updatedon
FROM rivereast_gallerycategories c, rivereast_gallery g
WHERE c.galleryCatID = g.galleryCatID
ORDER BY c.gallerycategory, g.ImageName
```

and then use

`<cfoutput query="ImagesCategoriesAndFiles" group="category">`

Cleaner code, less confusion.

See example here of how to use cfoutput for grouping record output: https://cfdocs.org/cfoutput